# all disk drives are visible but data in only one drive is not showing even though it is occupying some memory.

Tags: windows-7

I am using ACER laptop.
All my disk drives are visible but, only one drive which is also visible occupying some memory of data but data is not able to accessed.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that the missing partition is a system one. Possibly it contains a recovery partition put there by Acer.

It is marked as a hidden partition so that you can't accidentally mess up the data but it will still be accessible from the recovery tool that comes with the PC.

My advise is not to mess with it unless you really know what you are doing. It may be that the user guide for the PC or the Acer support pages have information on recovering the space.

Comment: I totally agree with Julian answer. It would be recovery partition.